# Option to export path alias not showing in view (pathauto is installed)

Tags: path-aliases, importing-exporting

On my new D 9.5.x site, I have pathauto installed, and it is working well. That is, neat alias URLs get generated for my articles as expected. I am now trying to export articles from the site. I have the [views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module installed, but when I create the export, I don't see the alias path available as a field to choose (as 'Content: Path' or anything else. The other article fields are available for selection and everything works with the export. Its just that the path is simply not available. Am I missing a setting somewhere? I have looked around, but unable to find any pointers.

I use the same modules on another old D8 site. Everything works perfectly there. I am able to export URL alias paths along with other article information. Makes me wonder if there is some setting from the other D8 site missing in my D9.5 site (note: the 2 sites are unrelated to each other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own query after spending some time looking around:

"Content: Path" was deprecated in 8.5 and removed in 9.

The alternative is to use "Content: Link to Content" and massage it. Described in this drupal.org link [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2018-03-08/missing-contentpath-in-views-after-upgrading-from-845-to).

NOTE: As the link suggests, this alternative may have issues with multilingual sites, which my site is not.

Comment: The links are missing.

Comment: berliner, fixed link now, sorry.